# Summary function extremely slow with nnet's multinom compared to regression function

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, multinomial, nnet

I'm using the `multinom()` function in the `nnet` package. My data has a little over a million rows and 4 independent variables. The `multinom()` function itself creates a model within ~15 minutes, and I can view coefficients.

I need to access them as an object though (with `$coefficients`) but I can't unless I save a `summary()` of it. When I try summarizing my model, it's run for over 30 minutes with no end in sight.

Is there any reason the `summary()` function takes so long, for what seems to be a basic reporting tool? How can I speed it up? Is there another way to access the coefficients?

Comment: Have you tried using the `broom` package to make it easier to access regression components?
https://github.com/hadley/broom

Comment: Take a look at `str(myMulitnomResult)` (or whatever name you gave it) to see what elements are stored in the regression results directly.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza Thank you I'll give that a shot

Comment: @Imo Thanks! I'm just afraid to stop the summary() function now to check... who knows how close I might be :/

Comment: I think that's because summary shows the standard errors of your coefficients, and requires calculating the Hessian & its inverse (the variance covariance matrix) and this can be very slow...

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the coefficients, use only the coef() method, which do much less computations.

Comment: That works great. The output of `summary(test)$coefficients` is the same as `coef(test)` but much quicker.